# UIButton setImage:forState: crashes on iOS 6 (SEGV_ACCERR at 0x8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uibutton

I receive many crash reports from users with iOS 6.X. Most of them using iPod4G, iPhone4S, iPhone4 or iPhone3GS. No iOS 7 user sent a crash report.

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x38dca5b0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                          0x31ae2a8f __35-[NSISLinearExpression description]_block_invoke_0 + 27
2   CoreFoundation                      0x31103fdf __CFSimpleMergeSort + 47
3   CoreFoundation                      0x3110406b __CFSimpleMergeSort + 187
4   CoreFoundation                      0x31075401 CFSortIndexes + 973
5   CoreFoundation                      0x310af641 -[NSArray sortedArrayFromRange:options:usingComparator:] + 705
6   CoreFoundation                      0x310af313 -[NSArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:] + 59
7   Foundation                          0x31ae29a7 -[NSISLinearExpression description] + 147
8   Foundation                          0x31ae016f __25-[NSISEngine description]_block_invoke_0 + 123
9   Foundation                          0x31ada075 -[NSISEngine enumerateRows:] + 185
10  Foundation                          0x31adffdf -[NSISEngine description] + 123
11  CoreFoundation                      0x3109a897 -[NSObject(NSObject) _copyDescription] + 35
12  CoreFoundation                      0x3110b2db __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 11139
13  CoreFoundation                      0x310a5fa9 CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArguments + 73
14  CoreFoundation                      0x3112a195 +[NSException raise:format:] + 57
15  Foundation                          0x31adc11f -[NSISEngine minimizeConstantInObjectiveRowWithHead:] + 191
16  Foundation                          0x31ade759 -[NSISEngine optimize] + 61
17  Foundation                          0x31ade8af -[NSISEngine withAutomaticOptimizationDisabled:] + 211
18  UIKit                               0x3336bc4f -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) removeConstraints:] + 283
19  UIKit                               0x32f48451 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) invalidateIntrinsicContentSize] + 73
20  UIKit                               0x331b7439 -[UIButton invalidateIntrinsicContentSize] + 61
21  UIKit                               0x32f4863f _UIButtonSetContentForState + 227
22  UIKit                               0x32f4870f -[UIButton setImage:forState:] + 23
23  XXXXX-Messenger                     0x000103bd -[MessageViewController setEditingMode:] (MessageViewController.m:1057)
24  XXXXX-Messenger                     0x0000f973 -[MessageViewController keyboardWasShown:] (MessageViewController.m:882)
25  CoreFoundation                      0x3107b037 _CFXNotificationPost + 1427
26  Foundation                          0x31991599 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 73
27  UIKit                               0x32fad879 -[UIInputViewTransition postNotificationsForTransitionStart] + 845
28  UIKit                               0x32fad04f -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) executeTransition:] + 923
29  UIKit                               0x32f389a3 -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 907
30  UIKit                               0x32f36cbb -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 475
31  UIKit                               0x330d6e99 -[UITextView becomeFirstResponder] + 361
32  UIKit                               0x33050c41 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 121
33  UIKit                               0x33050563 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) oneFingerTap:] + 1739
34  UIKit                               0x3304fd89 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 129
35  UIKit                               0x330173f5 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] + 393
36  UIKit                               0x33204a39 ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke_0543 + 49
37  UIKit                               0x32f3b82f _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 219
38  UIKit                               0x32f3a293 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 1275
39  UIKit                               0x32f451e7 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 767
40  UIKit                               0x32f44db3 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 91
41  UIKit                               0x32f32801 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 381
42  UIKit                               0x32f3211b _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6155
43  GraphicsServices                    0x34c355a3 _PurpleEventCallback + 591
44  GraphicsServices                    0x34c351d3 PurpleEventCallback + 35
45  CoreFoundation                      0x310ff173 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
46  CoreFoundation                      0x310ff117 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 139
47  CoreFoundation                      0x310fdf99 __CFRunLoopRun + 1385
48  CoreFoundation                      0x31070ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357
49  CoreFoundation                      0x31070d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
50  GraphicsServices                    0x34c342eb GSEventRunModal + 75
51  UIKit                               0x32f86301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
52  XXXXX-Messenger                     0x00015fef main (main.m:16)
```

This is the related code to line 23 of the stack trace

```
1057: [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationSmileyButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
1058: [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationSmileyButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

The code works fine for all my tests and I can't reproduce it, but i got about 2000 crash reports in 1 week.

Any ideas?

As requested

```
- (void)setEditingMode:(MessageViewEditingMode)editingMode
{
  _editingMode = editingMode;

  switch (editingMode) {

    //
    // None
    //

    case MessageViewEditingModeNone: {

      // SmileySelector ausblenden, falls vorhanden
      if (_smileySelector != nil && [self.view.subviews indexOfObject:_smileySelector] != NSNotFound) {
        [_smileySelector removeFromSuperview];
      }

      // ActionButton
      [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationActionButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationActionButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

      // ComposeView verschieben
      _composeViewMarginBottom.constant = 0.0f;

      // Keyboard ausblenden
      [_composeTextView resignFirstResponder];

    } break;

    //
    // Text
    //

    case MessageViewEditingModeText: {

      // ActionButton
      [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationSmileyButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationSmileyButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

      // ComposeView verschieben
      _composeViewMarginBottom.constant = -_keyboardHeight;

      // Keyboard einblenden
      [_composeTextView becomeFirstResponder];

    } break;

    //
    // Smiley
    //

    case MessageViewEditingModeSmiley: {

      // ActionButton
      [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationKeyboardButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [_actionButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"conversationKeyboardButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

      // Keyboard ausblenden
      [_composeTextView resignFirstResponder];

      // Anziegen, falls das noch nicht passiert ist
      if ([self.view.subviews indexOfObject:_smileySelector] == NSNotFound) {
        [self.view addSubview:_smileySelector];
      }

    } break;
  }

  // Layout anwenden
  [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
  }];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{   
  if (_keyboardAnimationDuration == 0 || _keyboardHeight == 0) {

    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    _keyboardAnimationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    _keyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
  }

  self.editingMode = MessageViewEditingModeText;
}
```

**Additional Infos**

What I am doing here is to replace an existing image of the UIButton with another image (conversationSmileyButton.png). As one can see before the exception is raised (stack trace line 14) there some constraint actions. Maybe iOS 6 can't handle that constraints correctly. Imo there should be a workaround for iOS 6.

Comment: Can you post the code for `keyboardWasShown:` and `setEditingMode:`?

Comment: i think your conversationSmileyButton.png may be wrong

Comment: @stosha conversationSmileyButton.png is part of my bundle and works fine. What can be wrong with it?

Comment: try change for _actionButton to @property(strong) UIButton* actionButton; and then change image file.

Comment: @stosha actionButton is already a strong property

Comment: I will try a workaround: I replace the UIButton with an UIView and an UITapGestureRecognizer